# Configure GridFS Chunksize in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I'm currently investigating to use MongoDB for storing E-Mail data. As E-Mails may become rather big in size (say 10 megs).

I believe that GridFS would be a good fit for this. What scares me a bit tough is, that the docs are not very clear about the shard size within gridFS. 
From what I understand is, that the shard size in gridFS is not equal to the normal shard size but defaults to 256kb. Which sounds to me like a big waste of space, as many e-mails will not exceed 50kb in size.

Is there a way to configure the shard size of files in GridFS to make it more adequate for storing mails?

Cheers, 
Matthias

Answer (score 4):

You do not have to worry about size. Even if the chunksize is 256kb, a document (containing your email) of 50kb, will still just use 50kb (+ minor overhead).

The chunksize is configured in the driver. For example with the PHP driver you would do:

```
$gridFs->storeFile( 'filename.txt', array( 'chunkSize' => 50 * 1024 ) );
```

And in the Java driver you'd call [setChunkSize](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSInputFile.html#setChunkSize%28long%29) on [GridFSInputFile](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.7.0/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFSInputFile.html).

But in general, you shouldn't have to worry about the chunkSize.

Comment: "Even if the chunksize is 256kb, a document (containing your email) of 50kb, will still just use 50kb (+ minor overhead)." ... This is consistent with my experience, but I have not seen this documented anywhere official. It is mentioned in [a mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/hrRlhOwGWWk%5B1-25%5D). Also [Robert Stam](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mongodb-user/H6gDl69o_o0%5B1-25%5D) writes, "The last chunk of a GridFS file is only as large as it needs to be, so
there won't be much overhead.

Comment: Is it good to have larger chunk size for, let's say, video files? For me, the file sizes could be upto 200mb. That will create a lot of chunks for each media file. Will that effect performance?

Comment: @Jayz MongoDB node manual has examples with larger chunks size: [Advanced GridFS or how not to run out of memory](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle2.html#advanced-gridfs-or-how-not-to-run-out-of-memory)

Comment: I am storing images of 2 sizes 4-5kb or 1-2 kb. So should i reduce the chuck size?? Will it make the performance better??