# GridFS and chunkSize - our GridFS database is too big comparing to real data/files stored

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

We have aplication in production which uses MongoDB (v. 3.4) as primary data store. We are using GridFS extensively and while db is growing we have some significant problems with its size. We have cca. 8000 files uploaded in GridFS (using Java driver) ... sum of file lengths is around 30GB, but database has 350GB in size ... so its 10x bigger. We cant see any reason except the chunkSize thing. We have several big files in db but most files are smaller then default 256kB chunkSize see example below.

I have read a few [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10384307/configure-gridfs-chunksize-in-mongodb)  that say dont worry  about it, real storage takes only the file size plus some bytes. But it doesn't look like in our database. Can someone confirm how this should work like? We have replica set with slaves where database size is 350Gb as well, so it doesn't seems to be some database corruption issue. We tried some database cleanups ... but no way.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("572c6877f0ea0bbab3b67015"),
    "metadata" : {
        "id" : "F735ADCACB662DD5C1257FAB0023B5CC",
        "name" : "file"
    },
    "filename" : "1150228.jpg",
    "aliases" : null,
    "chunkSize" : NumberLong(261120),
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2016-05-06T09:48:39.136Z"),
    "length" : NumberLong(36368),
    "contentType" : null,
    "md5" : "fd3393af027e0f1ff799ac4b1c117d58"
}
```

EDIT 1: I did `mongofiles -d database list` into file and openned in Excel and sumed up file sizes, shows 35GB.

**SOLVED:** 
I ran proposed command `mongo --quiet --eval 'db.fs.chunks.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "$files_id", chunks: {$sum: 1}}}]).forEach(function(f){print(f._id + "\t" + f.chunks)})'` to aggregate chunk collection by file_id and number of chunks related. In long file I found just one item with >20 milions chunks and this caused the problem. Now its quite easy to delete all these chunks and then shrink the database ...

Comment: What `db.stats()` says in terms of dataSize, storageSize, fileSize ? By "cleanups" you mean `compact` and `repair`?

Comment: I described details in post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070555/gridfs-chunks-collection-shows-big-storagesize-comparing-to-real-data-stored a few weeks ago with no response. And database is growing ...

Comment: `mongo --quiet --eval 'db.fs.chunks.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "$files_id", chunks: {$sum: 1}}}]).forEach(function(f){print(f._id + "\t" + f.chunks)})' ` outputs a tsv of file id and number of chunks. Check if number of files matches, and if product of total chunks and chunk size adds up.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex!! problem identified and solved. See my original post edits

Answer (score 0):

I ran proposed command

```
mongo --quiet --eval 'db.fs.chunks.aggregate([{$group:{_id: "$files_id", chunks: {$sum: 1}}}]).forEach(function(f){print(f._id + "\t" + f.chunks)})'
```

to aggregate chunks collection by file_id and number of chunks related. In long file I found just one item with >20 milions chunks and this caused the problem. Now its quite easy to delete all these chunks and then shrink the database ...